# Possible to have unique sculpts of linked mesh?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting, linked-data, layers

I have a character base mesh and want to make variations of it that share the same underlying topology, a common use-case for games. "Duplicate Linked" shares the underlying mesh in the way I want (any changes to the underlying topology like add/remove vertices, faces, edges, etc appear in all instances). Beyond topology changes, I want to then have localized instance-specific changes to the shape of the mesh (e.g. for different body types without changing vertices count/order).

Is there a way to do this in Blender? Or is the only way to have a single mesh and then use modifiers/layers for each variation and turn them on/off?

Comment: I don't think the current sculpt workflow allows this. You can try the boolean workflow though. Could you add an example picture with a few variations so we can see how complex the problem is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a certain way, you could implement this in [Shape Keys](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html#workflow). Your base mesh would be the `Basis` and each variation of it a shape key. This would theoretically allow you to manage/maintain only one rig for all characters.

(However, this depends very much on the complexity of your requirements of which you have given little indication)